IN Clause working opposite inside CASE Statement in sql
Having customer2 table
enter image description here
trying to execute below command
select AccountNO,id_Proof,
       CASE id_Proof
        when id_Proof in('Passport','PAN') then 'P'
        else id_Proof
       end as abc  
from customer2;

It working opposite
enter image description here
please suggest why IN clause getting opposite result inside case statement

Your syntax looks to be invalid for MySQL.  Can you post the actual code you are running?

case id_Proof ...  remove the id_Proof after the case as you are doing the comparison in the when branch.

Although incorrect the statement is not SYNTACTICALLY incorrect https://dbfiddle.uk/KWoZqZCr and it runs as op states with inverted expected results

What DB are you using?

@P.Salmon It is incorrect in Postgres https://dbfiddle.uk/p8eYm26x and SQL Server https://dbfiddle.uk/tpimIWw3 and Oracle https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0QnWrHk oddly enough in SQLIte it returns all of them without using the when https://dbfiddle.uk/RnVVKkhL Long and short of it: MySQL's type conversion is weird.

You use CASE operator in the next syntax variation:

CASE value WHEN compare_value THEN result [WHEN compare_value THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END

So in when id_Proof in('Passport','PAN') then 'P' the expression id_Proof in('Passport','PAN') is treated as compare_value.
Depends on current id_Proof it produces 1, 0 or NULL.
Then id_Proof is compared with this 1, 0 or NULL.
If the value is 1, then id_Proof is 'Passport' or 'PAN', and the comparing produces FALSE, the result in this branch is not used. If the value is 0, then string-type value of id_Proof is converted to numeric datatype which produces 0 if the value have NOT a numeric prefix, and the comparing produces TRUE, the result in this branch is used (if a value starts from a digit then the convertion poroduces non-zero value and the comparing produces FALSE). If the value is NULL then any column value produces FALSE.
Finally almost any value produces a result which looks like revertion. You may test this using the row where id_Proof value is, for example, '0 Passport' and '1 Passport'..
You must use 2nd form of CASE operator: CASE WHEN id_Proof IN ('Passport','PAN') ...

read the answer from @Akina or modify your case so:
select AccountNO,id_Proof,
   CASE TRUE
    when name IN('Passport','PAN') then 'P'
    else name
   end as abc 
from customer2;

the result of name IN('Passport','PAN') is TRUE(1) OR FALSE(0) and it compares with the value from CASE TRUE
sample
select name in('Passport','PAN') as result, name
,       CASE TRUE
        when name IN('Passport','PAN') then 'P'
        else name
       end as abc  
from test_table LIMIT 5;

1   Passport.       P
0   Lorna Duran     Lorna Duran
1   PAN.            P
0   Allen Gibbons   Allen Gibbons
0   Melisa Porter   Melisa Porter

@ysth
1. CASE:
The CASE form is used when you need to check multiple conditions and return a value based on those conditions. It follows the pattern:
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    ...
    ELSE elseResult
END

Here, each condition is checked, and if a condition is met, the corresponding result value is returned. If none of the conditions are met, elseResult, if specified, is returned.
2. CASE...WHEN:
The CASE...WHEN form is a shorter version of CASE, requiring less typing when you only need to check simple conditions. It follows the pattern:
CASE expression
    WHEN value1 THEN result1
    WHEN value2 THEN result2
    ...
    ELSE elseResult
END

Here, the expression expression is evaluated and compared against the specified values. If a match is found, the corresponding result value is returned.
3. CASE...WHEN...ELSE:
This form is similar to the previous one, but it allows for specifying multiple conditions, and an ELSE part is always required. It follows the pattern:
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    ...
    ELSE elseResult
END

Here, each condition is checked, and if a condition is met, the corresponding result value is returned. If none of the conditions are met, elseResult is returned.
Understanding these forms will help you implement conditional logic effectively in your SQL queries, depending on your application requirements.

CASE TRUE is just confusing, no reason to do this instead of just fixing it to be CASE WHEN (the other case syntax)

@ysth - Sure, no problem!, but no reason to downgrade the answer either. It is important to distinguish between the different forms of CASE in MySQL because they work differently. I will describe these for you here in an answer

@ysth - sorry - I'am also find your usage better, but he ask why it not work
